# Is there an "WITH" clause in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am a new user of *bigquery*. I used to use *Postgresql* and the `WITH` clause...

I have written multiple queries. Results of these queries need to be joined in order to create a single table (all results have a common key column).

Is there an equivalent of the `WITH` clause? I am reluctant to use sub-queries as my code will be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 8):

BigQuery does support `WITH` clause in Standard SQL dialect. Documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause

Comment: Great! Thank for headsup!

Comment: This and other SQL improvements are released to selected testers right now. Next step will open them to more users. Progress can be tracked in https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=448

Comment: Available now, details at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Answer (score 1):

WITH doesn't come with BigQuery
How about using VIEWs?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will have a look at the documention